# Continuity of real part of a complex function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, continuity

Consider a function $g(z)$ which is analytic on $\mathbb{C}_+$, and its range is contained in $\mathbb{C}_-$. Suppose that $g$ has a continuous extension to $\mathbb{C}_+ \cup \mathbb{R}$, denoted by $\tilde{g}$. Now, define the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as:
$$
f(x) = {\rm Re} \{\tilde{g}(x) \}
$$

Is $f(x)$ a continuous function?

What about the imaginary part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\tilde{g}$ and $\text{Re}$ are continuous, it follows that $f$ is continuous.